# Bootstrap 3.1 with laravel 4.0

Tags: laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem to display confirmation dialog box when I click the delete button it show the confirmation dialog and also submit the form without clicking the button in confirmation dialog box.

I'm using bootstrap and laravel. here is the code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this data(s) ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#confirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // Pass form reference to modal for submission on yes/ok
            var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');
            $(this).find('.modal-footer #confirm').data('form', form);
        });

        <!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
        $('#confirmDelete').find('.modal-footer #confirm').on('click', function(){
            $(this).data('form').submit();
        });


{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('subscription.delete.all'), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' type='submit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDelete">
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete
        </button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

on top of your modal add this

```
<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDelete">
delete
```

and in your modal code change the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
```

by your delete button code

```
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('subscription.delete.all')......
```

Answer (score 0):

Change button (inside the form) type from "submit" to "button"